# How to concatenate two strings in c language

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers

I have the below code which concatenates two strings. The first one with while condition works, but the second one with for loop fails. I ran them independently with the below inputs.

```
int original[100]="c" , add[50] = "pgm";
concatenate_string(original, add);   
printf("String after concatenation is \"%s\"\n", original);
//strcat(original,add);
//printf("strcat is : %s",original);


void concatenate_string(char *original, char *add)
    {
       while(*original)
          original++;

       while(*add)
       {
          *original = *add;
          add++;
          original++;
       }
       *original = '\0';
    }

void strcat(char *original,char *add)
{
    for (;*original++;);
    for (;*add;)
         *original++=*add++;
    *(original)='\0';

}
```

Comment: Note: you can avoid `*(original)='\0';` in second function, infact you can just write: `for (;*original++=*add++;)`

Comment: Your second version uses a reserved name, by the way. User-defined function names cannot begin with `str`.

Answer (score 7):

Because in second code, you are appending string after nul `\0` symbol:

```
for (;*original++;);
        ^  always increments, even after nul found
```

should be:

```
for (;*original; original++);
```

**Note:**

for code:

```
for (;*original++;);
```

is equivalent to

```
while (*original++);
```

But not what you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Your second version does an extra `++` before the second loop starts. Try adding `--original;` between the two loops, or as the initialization in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void string_add(char *original,char *add) {
    int i = 0,j,length = 0;
    i = strlen(original);
    length = strlen(add);
    for(j = 0; j<length; j++,i++)
        original[i] = add[j];
}

int main()
{
    char original[20] = "I am from ", add[10] = "india";
    string_add(original, add);
    printf("Concatinated : %s\n",original);
    return 0;
}
```